# Switching from theoretical to experimental after masters in electronics

Tags: phd, masters, electrical-engineering

I am a final semester masters student in the US and the topic I am currently working on as a part of my masters thesis is purely computational. I will be applying for Fall 2021 PhD programs and I came to realize that there are only a few research groups working in computational electronics. Is it common to switch from theoretical to experimental after Masters?

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/147930/switching-fields-after-ma

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/changing-fields

Comment: It's not common but there is no reason why you could not do it.  It might not even be difficult.